# When to bundle a Typescript package and when to use tsc?

Tags: typescript, npm, rollup, gdi-cms

I understand I have two general options when it comes to publishing a Typescript NPM package (library, not client):

### 1. Use `Typescript`'s compiler

Either run:

```
tsc
```

and have a `tsconfig.json` define the `outDir`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "outDir": "dist",
    },
    "exclude": ["dist/**"]
}
```

The output would be `multiple` javascript files and everything will work as expected.

```
- dist
    - dir/file1.js
    - dir/file2.js
    - index.js
```

### 2. Use `Rollup`

Join all the files in a bundle by using `rollup`:

```js
// rollup.config.js
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';

export default {
  input: 'src/index.ts',
  output: {
    dir: 'dist',
    format: 'cjs'
  },
  plugins: [typescript()]
};
```

The output would be a `single` large bundled JS file:

```
- dist
    - main.umd.js
```

As both are working as expected, I am wondering:

1. When to pick one over the other?
2. What are the benefits of bundling as it requires an extra step, requires to define globals to prevent dependencies from being bundled too and in general the `dist` folder is less readable?
3. If using `tsc` is sufficient, does `rollup` shines for bundling web applications and clients, rather than library packages?
4. Would tree shaking be possible with both approaches? is it solely a client bundler configuration?

Comment: Building libraries => `tsc` and friends, building applications => bundlers and friends.

Comment: Most bundlers support library mode so I guess it is recommended for something.
https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode
And a quote for rollup homepage: "Rollup is a module bundler for JavaScript which compiles small pieces of code into something larger and more complex, such as a *library* or application. "

Answer (score 2):

One of the big factors for me using using `tsc` is whether my project utilizes modules.

If I want to transpile my code into ESM and CJS then it's preferable to have the CJS be multiple files so that the user of the package can be selective when they import the module for a smaller bundle size.

If the user is importing the package with ESM:

```js
import p from 'my-package'
```

then it doesn't matter if the code is a large file or multiple files - as long as the files don't contain dynamic imports then the user's build tool will be able to statically analyze my package and tree shake the unused code from the package.

If the user is importing the package with CJS:

```
const p = require('my-package')
```

then their build tool won't even try tree shaking the code (unless they use some [CJS plugin](https://github.com/indutny/webpack-common-shake)) because **all** CJS imports are dynamic.

The user can get around this by importing only the file they need from my package:

```js
const d = require('my-package/d')
```

which is a behaviour that isn't possible if the CJS was bundled into one large file.

This real world example wouldn't be possible if `lodash` was bundled:

[image]